# не могу передать функции строку в СИ++

Tags: c++

сделал все как в книге, но чет не хочет

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct mystr {
    void buildstr(char* s);
    void printstr();
private:
    char str[100];
};

void mystr::buildstr(char* s) {
    if (!*s) *str = '\0';
    else strcat(str, s);
}

void mystr::printstr(){
    cout << str << endl;
}
int main() {
    mystr s;
    s.buildstr("sdfdf");
    s.buildstr("fdsf");
    s.printstr();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция должна принимать указатель на константную строку — литерал менять нельзя...

```
void buildstr(const char* s);
```

Только это не всё — у вас `str` неинициализированный массив... Если компилятор позволяет, напишите

```
char str[100] = "";
```

вместо просто

```
char str[100];
```

Comment: спасибо, просто не понимаю, почему в книге не так

Comment: Возможно, книга старая. Что за книга?

Comment: полный справочник по СИ++ Герберд Шилд, вроде 2006 год

Comment: Ну так с того времени сменилось 4 стандарта... :(

Comment: Кстати, если ответ устроил — то птичка для его принятия слева от ответа.

Comment: что такое птичка?

Comment: Ну фигура в виде буквы V, если так понятнее...

Comment: все, увидел галочку